# html layout getting changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am a newbie to css, html5 and jquery. I'm trying to build a menu in which list items appear and disappear on hover. As mplungjan  had asked, The code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m5ab6/

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="drop.css"
>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="main">
        <ul id="topbar">
            <li class="droplist">Fruits
                <ul class="subdrop">
                    <li>Apple</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="droplist">Vegetables
                <ul class="subdrop"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
<!-- <script src="drop.js"></script> -->

</html>
```

Css is:-

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

.main{
    width: device-width;
    height:200px;
}
#topbar
{
    background-color: black;
    color: grey;
    /*display: none;*/
    list-style-type: none;
}

.droplist
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.subdrop{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript is:-

```
function hoverinfunc(){
    $(".subdrop").show(500);
    //$("subdrop").css({"position:"})
}
function hoveroutfunc(){
    $(".subdrop").hide(500);
}
$(document).ready(
        $("li.droplist").hover(hoverinfunc, hoveroutfunc)
        );
```

**The problem**: Hovering out from Fruits/Vegetables changes the layout of Vegetables. Normally, Vegetables are placed to the right of Fruits. But, continuous hovering in and out of fruits/vegetables causes vegetables to come under fruits. My requirement is that the position of vegetables should always be to the right of fruits

**My solution (could be a naive one)**: I add   `float:left;` in the `.droplist'` in the css file. But, because of this, the background color is lost.

Please help me understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle.net

Comment: AND LEAVE The code here too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5ab6/2/)**

```
function hoverinfunc() {
    $(".subdrop", this).stop().show(100);
}
function hoveroutfunc() {
    $(".subdrop", this).stop().hide(300);
}

$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand

    $("li.droplist").hover(hoverinfunc, hoveroutfunc);

});
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}
#topbar {
    background-color: black;
    color: grey;
    list-style: none;
}
.droplist {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; /*for padding to work*/
    padding: 20px;
}
.subdrop {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;             /* to properly align on the parent LI left */
    background:black;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    white-space:nowrap; /*for text to overflow parent LI size*/
}
```

---

Another simple and nice way to do your JS would be: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m5ab6/4/)

```
$("li.droplist").hover(function(){
    $("> ul", this).stop().slideToggle(280);
});
```

and if you want to control the animation speed differently depending on the event type, it's quite easy: passing the event argument (`.hover()` method listens for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) into a Conditional Operator (`?:`) like:

```
$("li.droplist").hover(function( e ){
    $("> ul", this).stop().slideToggle(e.type=='mouseenter'?100:300);
});
```

is `mouseenter` ? (TRUE) animate 100ms : (ELSE [is `mouseleave`]) animate 300ms

Comment: Thanks for the comments in the code. Really helps a beginner like me

Comment: @GodMan you're welcome! Sometimes it really helps to use a tool like http://jsBin.com while creating some basic stuff, cause immediately, while writing your code, you can see the changes on screen and it really helps to visually fast-learn what's every CSS property about and what happens if modified.

Comment: Cool. I'll use tools like jsbin.com and jsfiddle.net. They are helpful indeed. Also, I like the use of `this` in your answer as it answered another doubt of mine. you rock

Comment: @GodMan `> ul` *means immediate children of*; and `this` means *Of this, hovered, element.* Why? Cause if you remove `>` and in the case you desired to have multiple nested submenus it would open them all at-once. If you remove `this` than it might select all the selectors instead of the desired `hover` one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely position your sub menu:

```
.subdrop{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m5ab6/1/)

Comment: Actually, the reason for this error is unknown to me. Could you please explain in your answer as well?

Answer (score -1):

Why use javascript for this at all?  Only to get the slide effect?

A basic "show submenu on hover" can be easily done with fairly simple CSS and no javascript.  For example, using your HTML and changing the CSS to

```
.main{
    width: device-width;
    height:200px;
}
#topbar, .subdrop
{
    background-color: black;
    color: grey;
    /*display: none;*/
    list-style-type: none;
}

.droplist
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.subdrop{
    display: none;
}
.subdrop li{
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.droplist:hover .subdrop{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can remove the javascript entirely. See it working on http://jsfiddle.net/QnwcW/2/

If you want animations these can be added using CSS3.  A quick google (looks OK, but I've not actually used this page) produces for example http://candpgeneration.com/toys/CSS3-dropdown-tut.php

Just an alternative. I think it's cleaner to stick to CSS for this kind of thing whenever possible rather than use javascript when it's not needed.

Comment: Here is your suggested example with just a submenu added to *Vegetables* http://jsfiddle.net/QnwcW/3/ I find it quite strange. Also a good *User Interface* implies the use of simple animations. If you don't have any code to share about how to do it in pure CSS3 (there are already topics about that on SO) you should not paste links to external sites without code coverage, cause those sites might o down one day and your link (and answer) be useless.

Comment: Also the guy in the link you posted created dropdown menus implying specific submenu heights in order to to (a so-called "*CSS3 MAGIC*"...) This seems than like a pretty bad resource to achieve the desired, cause by just adding an additional submenu item implies a webmaster to sniff into the CSS, find the submenu line, and change it's height. So -1. CSS3 *magic* should be achieved by animating a `max-height` property. Again, more on that topic here on SO.

Comment: @Adam: This snippet is just a small example of what I'm planning to do on the website. So, I need jquery to do more stuff on it, as it seems easy to use. However, I'll surely have a look at CSS animations (I've only done some tutorial on CSS 2 but CSS3 is pending).

Comment: @GodMan forget that link. (read the reason in my comment above.)

Comment: @GodMan regarding my comment here's also an example on how to achieve it usign CSS3 and the mentioned `max-height` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076846/css3-hidden-div-fade-on-in-hover , still my suggestion is to use jQuery, for the reason that even using `max-height` you need to set a max-height, which might not be correct in production after a webmaster populates it's submenu with too much content -> exceeding that max-height value.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I shouldn't have posted that link.  I posted it as an exmaple not neccessarily as the full solution and was trying to say "there's lots of stuff on CSS animations out there - this happens to be the first result my google search found and looks like it might do what you want".  All I was trying to point out is that you don't necessarily need javascript for dropdown menus, even with animations.  My experience is that it is cleaner to do menus with CSS than with javascript.

Comment: @Adam it has been a topic discussed all over the place among UX and UI specialists, (they even get into details about how long in ms is the animation plausible to the eye...) So, a pure CSS solution should always exist in your code (for JS disabled browsers (crap)) but also a JS implementation for a good User Interface! (the reason is to avoid *flashy* elements appearance on screen, the user should be able to follow up with the page behavior.)

Comment: @Roko  Fair enough - although a lot of the discussions about the UI/UX and how fast the animations should be apply, etc. equally to CSS and javascript solutions - they are essentially about what end result is desirable as a UI, rather than how to acheive it technically

Comment: @Adam exactly! All the best desirable solutions should be merged together!